# Converting any Jquery Plugin to .NET Server Control

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, jquery-plugins

What you should know if you need to convert a jquery plugin to .NET server control (.ascx).

Is there anybody have a good tutorial or would like his ideas what's best and how you should do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following link

[jQuery Asp.net Controls by David Taylor](http://jqueryaspnetcontrols.codeplex.com/)

[DJ-Jquery Web Controls for asp.net](http://dj.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think is possible, in general server controls are server side while by design jquery plugins are client side, why would you incapsulate what is already working server side into a server control which renders the same client side code?

Comment: take a look at http://www.ext.net/ for something similar, but with ExtJS. It makes building a UI a *lot* easier and less error prone when it's created in **validated** markup, rather than javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues:

1) Self-registration of scripts and css - any server control should be completely self-contained, so it should be able to ensure its own resources are available

2) Naming container safety (e.g. you can't really hard-code references to server objects, or the code won't be reusable). You can't really get away with using `Static` client IDs, this would break naming container safety from the get-go. So you need a way to pass references to the client script dynamically.

3) Hooking with asp.net client event model, e.g. to update data passed from the server after partial postbacks, if you want them to work right in UpdatePanels